# Removing Values from Input on deselect, with jsfiddle

Tags: jquery, input, click

I managed to achieve what I wanted but I can't seem to understand the logic behind the following:

HTML For Example:

```
<input id="field-one" type="text" />
<ul class="clicks">
<li>15</li>
<li>20</li>
<li>30</li>
</ul>
```

and JQuery

```
$('.clicks li').bind('click', function(){
$(this).toggleClass('selected');

if($(this).hasClass('selected')) {
var numbers = $(this).html();
var joinNumbers = $('input#field-one').val().replace(/^,|,$/g, '').split(',');

joinNumbers.push(numbers);

$('input#field-one').val(joinNumbers.join());
} else {



}
```

});

I've managed to add the numbers as you click on them. What I want to achieve is to be able to remove the numbers as you deselect them.

For example if I click on 15 I want only 15 to be removed and so on.

As you can see I Am checking for selected class and executing the code when selected is present but i can't really think of any solution for the else at this moment, any help is much appreciated, thanks...

[Here is working JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b6f1w13y/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$('.clicks li').on('click', function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('selected');
  var values = $('.clicks li.selected').map(function(){
  
  return $(this).text();
  }).get()
$("#field-one").val(values.join(","))
});
```

```css
.clicks {
  padding: 0;
}

.clicks li {
  cursor: pointer;
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
}

.selected {
  background: #AAAAAA;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="field-one" type="text" />
<ul class="clicks">
  <li>15</li>
  <li>20</li>
  <li>30</li>
</ul>
```

1. use `.map()` to put `li` values with selected class
2. use `.join()` to join with `,`

Comment: @Novakinify happy coding mate

Answer (score 0):

better approach is to get all elements with class selected and concat their values to the input on every click. I didn't use jQuery for a long time, so maybe I broke the each syntax, but the idea is there ;)

```
$('.clicks li').bind('click', function(){
  $(this).toggleClass('selected');

  var inputText = "";
  $(this).parent.find('.selected').each(function(li) {
    inputText += (inputText == "" ? "" : ", ")+li.html();
  }
  $('input#field-one').val(inputText);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer :D

Answer (score 0):

Using `Array.indexOf()` and `Array.splice()`

```
$('.clicks li').bind('click', function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('selected');
    var numbers = $(this).html();
    var joinNumbers = $('input#field-one').val().replace(/^,|,$/g, '').split(',');
    var index = joinNumbers.indexOf(numbers);
    if (index > -1) joinNumbers.splice(index, 1);
    else joinNumbers.push(numbers);

    $('input#field-one').val(joinNumbers.join());
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer :D